# Apache HttpAsyncClient to upload application data

Tags: apache, upload

where I can find detailed document for Apache HttpAsyncClient? Or example how to post application data to server by writing to stream? The example shipped with download only do download, and there is no API document. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an upload example I am currently using in production:

https://github.com/boxerab/sardine/blob/asynch-client/src/main/java/com/github/sardine/impl/SardineAsyncImpl.java